net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on API call to my backend
For a hobby project (books.cihanbatasul.com) I have a golang application that runs on my backend as a docker container. The application has a database container and the API container.
The error happens on my frontend when I try to interact with the backend (register, searching for a book. It says:
index-149c02ff.js:166 
        
        
       POST https://cihanbatasul.com:8081/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
st @ index-149c02ff.js:166
(anonymous) @ index-149c02ff.js:166
await in (anonymous) (async)
Nb @ index-149c02ff.js:37
Tb @ index-149c02ff.js:37
Ub @ index-149c02ff.js:37
nf @ index-149c02ff.js:37
se$2 @ index-149c02ff.js:37
(anonymous) @ index-149c02ff.js:37
Rk @ index-149c02ff.js:40
Jb @ index-149c02ff.js:37
hd @ index-149c02ff.js:37
fd @ index-149c02ff.js:37
ed @ index-149c02ff.js:37
index-149c02ff.js:166 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at st (index-149c02ff.js:166:107788)
    at index-149c02ff.js:166:98541

My main.go file accepts three origins:
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/tls"
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/base64"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/cihanbatasul/bookapi/internal/models"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

type application struct {
    error_log    *log.Logger
    info_log     *log.Logger
    books        *models.BookServiceImplementation
    users        *models.UserServiceImplementation
    user_helpers *models.UserHelperServiceImplementation
    ai           *models.AiServiceImplementation
}

func openDB(dsn string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return db, nil
}

func generateRandomSecret(length int) (string, error) {
    secretBytes := make([]byte, length)
    _, err := rand.Read(secretBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(secretBytes), nil
}

func main() {

    if err := godotenv.Load(".env"); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Fehler beim Laden der .env-Datei %v", err)
    }

    cors := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"https://cihanbatasul.com", "http://localhost", "https://books.cihanbatasul.com"},
        AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Content-Type"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })

    addr := flag.String("addr", ":8081", "HTTPS network address")
    flag.Parse()

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", os.Getenv("HOST"), os.Getenv("DB_PORT"), os.Getenv("USER_NAME"), os.Getenv("PASSWORD"), os.Getenv("DB_NAME"))

    info_log := log.New(os.Stdout, "INFO\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime)
    error_log := log.New(os.Stderr, "ERROR\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    db, err := openDB(dsn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", dsn)
        error_log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    app := &application{
        error_log:    error_log,
        info_log:     info_log,
        books:        &models.BookServiceImplementation{},
        users:        &models.UserServiceImplementation{DB: db},
        user_helpers: &models.UserHelperServiceImplementation{},
        ai:           &models.AiServiceImplementation{},
    }

    handler := cors.Handler(app.Routes())

    certPath := "certs/cert.pem"
    keyPath := "certs/privkey.pem"
    // Load TLS certificate and key
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certPath, keyPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading certificate and key:", err)
    }

    // Create TLS config
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    // Create HTTPS server
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:      *addr,
        ErrorLog:  app.error_log,
        Handler:   handler,
        TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
    }

    info_log.Println("Starting server on port ", *addr)

    // Start HTTPS server
    err = srv.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
    if err != nil {
        app.error_log.Fatal(err)
    }
}


When the error happens the API container exits:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS                                       NAMES
ca807a67f67a   booksbackend           "./main"                 14 minutes ago   Exited (1) 4 minutes ago                                               booksbackend_container
3516610db914   booksbackend_db        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes              0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   booksbackend_db_container
6a2f27202298   portfolio2023:latest   "portfolio2023 -p 80…"   2 days ago       Up 2 days                  0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   portfolio_backend

with the docker logs saying this:
intero@231:~$ sudo docker logs booksbackend_container
ERROR   2024/06/12 18:13:55 main.go:75: dial tcp 92.205.28.231:5432: connect: connection timed out

I don't know what the issue could be. I hope someone can help me solve this problem. Sadly I don't have a lot of experience which is why I don't know which kind of information would be valuable in solving this issue. If you need further information, please let me know.
Edit:
The .env variables:
PORT=8081
DB_DOCKER_CONTAINER=booksbackend_db_container
DB_NAME=booksbackend_db
USER_NAME=intero
PASSWORD=thepassword
HOST=cihanbatasul.com
DB_PORT=5432
BINARY=bookapi

The Dockerfile for the database is this:
FROM postgres:12-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_USER=intero
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=thepassword
ENV POSTGRES_DB=booksbackend_db
EXPOSE 5432


COPY migrations/000001_books_migrations.up.sql /docker- 
entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

While the Dockerfile  for the application is this:
FROM golang:1.22.0-alpine3.19 AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main ./cmd/web

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY .env /app/

COPY --from=builder /app/main .

RUN mkdir -p certs
COPY certs/* certs/

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["./main"]


How are you starting the container(s)?  It looks like the real problem might be that the application container is failing to connect to the database container; how is that configured (what are DB_HOST et al.)?

Hey, thank you for the help. I just edited the original post with the Dockerfiles for the database and application.

what happens if you try to request directly to https://cihanbatasul.com:8081/register from postman or a web browser tab?

Do you need to expose your database to the internet? I can see it's up and accepting connections (others will too which means it's likely it will be probed). As the database and your app are running on the same machine there is no real need to connect via the external IP.  As you appear to be starting both containers at the same time there is a good chance that your database has not completed starting up when the app attempts to connect (you may want to retry the db.Ping()).

To @Brits's point, you should be able to use a Docker-internal hostname (the Compose service name of the other container, or the docker run --name if you're launching the containers directly) as the database HOST; you probably don't want the externally-accessible DNS name here.  You can connect between containers even if one of the containers doesn't have Compose ports: or docker compose -p published ports.
